# Undefined value after subscribe in angular 2, but in templateurl it can show up

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to process value from my service it return undefined value. But strangely if i access it directly to template, it was work.

this is my service

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Globals} from "../globals";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {DetailprodComponent} from './detailprod.component';
import {Home} from '../home/home';
import { ActivatedRoute,Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class DetailprodService {
    private id:string;
    constructor (private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {let   id = params['id'];this.id = id;});
    }

    getDetail(){
        return this.http.get(Globals.server+'/product/'+this.id)
                    .map(res=> res.json());
    }

}
```

and in component, in onInit method i put

```
this.detailprodService.getDetail()
        .subscribe(details => this.product_rating = details.product_rating,
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
this.getstars(this.product_rating);
```

then if in HTML i put {{product_rating}} it shows the output. but if i process it further in component, it resulted undefined value. i sent product_rating to method this.getstars(this.product_rating)

```
getstars(x){
    alert(x)
    if (x == 2){
      alert("1");
      this.starspath ="imagemanagement/1stars.png";
    }else if (x == 4){
      alert("2");
      this.starspath ="imagemanagement/2stars.png";
    }else if (x == 6){
      alert("3");
      this.starspath ="imagemanagement/3stars.png";
    }else if (x == 7){
      alert("4");
      this.starspath ="imagemanagement/4stars.png";
    }else if (x == 10){
      alert("5");
      this.starspath ="imagemanagement/5stars.png";
    }
  }
```

any answers will be highly appreciated ...

Comment: Could you share component code. At least the part where you call `getstars().`

Comment: i  added it, it is exactly below the subscribe code :)

Comment: variable product_rating should be inside the component file.

Comment: actually it is in component file, thing which you see in service just my mistake, it never be used in service. i was already delete it. thanks for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below:

```
   this.detailprodService.getDetail()
            .subscribe(details => {
this.product_rating = details.product_rating;
this.getstars(this.product_rating);
}, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

you should wait for subscribtion to process the value.

Comment: thanks , i believe that getstars should be inside subscribe. i was trying such that code, but in wrong way. thanks again, you save my time ...